# Android Location services runtime permission error

Tags: android, locationmanager, runtime-permissions

I am unable to Gradle build my app even after handling the Runtime permissions based on the following link

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions

I am receiving "Unable to resolve symbol "locationListener" and the message "Call requires permissions that may be rejected by user"

Can you please assist in what is wrong with the program or what cases have not been handled properly

Mainactivity file

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener  {

```
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private GoogleMap mMap;
private String[] places;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location loc;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
String lat, lon;
Location mLastLocation;


   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buildGoogleApiClient();

    if (BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE < 23) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
    } else {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
        {
            //Request for Permission
          // ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                // Display UI and wait for user interaction
            }
            else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        1);
            }
        } else {
            // permission has been granted, continue as usual
            Location myLocation =
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        }
    }

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Connect the client.
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");

    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every 10 seconds

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        lon = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    }}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
    {
                    Location myLocation =
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);            
       }
    }

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has failed");
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG, location.toString());
    //txtOutput.setText(location.toString());

    //txtOutput.setText(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
}
```

}

Comment: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);`
Use **this** instead of **locationListener**

Comment: Tried the this option, but still receive the same error. No changes